# Plotting Polylines using Snap to Road in Android Studio

Tags: java, google-maps, android-studio

Hello guys can you help me how to plot a polylines
right now i have the i got the json from the googlemap 
My question is How to plot polylines using this json

```
{
  "snappedPoints": [
    {
      "location": {
        "latitude": 14.554309626417714,
        "longitude": 121.01901383856206
      },
      "originalIndex": 0,
      "placeId": "ChIJ62cMsw_JlzMRCXM5jZU83BM"
    },
    {
      "location": {
        "latitude": 14.554430199999995,
        "longitude": 121.01905140000001
      },
      "placeId": "ChIJ62cMsw_JlzMRCXM5jZU83BM"
    },
    {
      "location": {
        "latitude": 14.5544967,
        "longitude": 121.01907999999997
      },
      "placeId": "ChIJ62cMsw_JlzMRCXM5jZU83BM"
    },
    {
      "location": {
        "latitude": 14.554658699999997,
        "longitude": 121.01916489999999
      },
      "placeId": "ChIJ62cMsw_JlzMRCXM5jZU83BM"
    },
    {
      "location": {
        "latitude": 14.55596745847264,
        "longitude": 121.02005815511896
      },
      "originalIndex": 1,
      "placeId": "ChIJ62cMsw_JlzMRCXM5jZU83BM"
    }
  ]
}
```

I already converted this into string,

```
  RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url = String.format("https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/snapToRoads?path=" + EncodingSnap + "&interpolate=true&key=AIzaSyBNixSdb4ofwpeXzZ7_MXoKnrps352Ji7U");
        JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
                (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        SnapToRoadInfo scheduleRequest = new Gson().fromJson(response.toString(), SnapToRoadInfo.class);


                    }
                }, new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {


                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Log.e("Error", error.toString());
                    }
                });
        requestQueue.add(jsObjRequest);
```

im using Volley for serialize the code and send it to the google map api, then , Right now i have the result, now how to decode this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Poly decoding and encoding in [this library](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/)

sample code:

```
    List<LatLng> list = PolyUtil.decode(encodedLine);
    PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions().width(10).color(Color.BLUE);
    options.addAll(list);

    mMap.addPolyline(options);
```

Comment: actually I\m using that what i need is a HOW can you give me example for this one?

Comment: Added sample code. If that is what you are asking for.

Comment: trying to use your code but its giving me a fatal error, I create my own method, right now im using gson for parse and convert this to latlang , also im using volly for serialize and send it to the snap points.

Comment: which Latitude n longitude are you using from above JSon response ?